# Loading Excel Files in Different Languages Using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have 86 countries each of which has a folder placed in the CountryFolder: e.g.

```
C:\Users\Countries\Algeria
```

And in each country folder there is an Excel Sheet in that Country's language:

```
C:\Users\Countries\Algeria\Excel Sheet.xlsx
```

I have a ForEach Loop package which iterates through all the countries extracting data from the Excel Sheets. The sheets are all in the same format, but in different languages.
My SSIS package runs through all the English countries loading the sheets on to the database, but throws an error when it gets to Spanish and other non-English countries because it uses column names to map. Table Column names are in English so they do not match the Excel column names for the non-English countries

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `ForEach` Loop to iterate the `folder`.Inside `ForEach Loop` use `FileSystem` task to copy the particular file to a different location .Then with the help of `Script task` read the original Excel file and change the column heders to English Name so that your `Data Flow Task` works for all the excels having different `langauages`

```
 ConnString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;   
 Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";"
 ,@ForEachVariable);
```

`Note :@ForEachVariable` contains the file location  stored in a variable by `ForEach` Loop

```
//open the connection
OleDbCommand query = 
 new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ["xlWorksheet"$]", objConn); 

//popluate the Datetable and get the column names using 
dt.Columns[0].ColumnName
```

Once you get the column name change it to your English name in the Excel and then process the file using `DFT`

Package Design :-

[image]

In this way you can `reuse` your existing Data Flow Task